# Amazon S3 Backup

Tags: php, scripting, cron

In php what is the best way to run a script after one has finished for exmaple i have these two files.

My backup file.

```
<?php
require 'back-up.php'; 

#!/bin/php -d max_execution_time = 3600 

$backup_dirs = array('../bu/'); 
$backup = new backupclass($backup_dirs); 
$backup->backup('filesys','files/');
?>
```

The i have my amazon s3 upload file.

```
<?php

require_once('S3.php');

$s3 = new S3('S3KEY', 'S3SECRETKEY');

$baseurl = "/home/mlcreative/public_html/bu/files";

if ($handle = opendir('./files/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            if ($s3->putObjectFile("files/$file", "testingmlc333", "lighthouse/$file", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {

                    echo "<strong>We successfully uploaded your file.</strong>";
                    if (file_exists($baseurl . '/' . $file)) { unlink ($baseurl . '/' . $file); }
}else{
                    echo "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";
}

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Ok so at the moment i have a cron job setup to running the backup php file then an hour later run the amazon upload php file.

What i am asking is how i could combine these to script so i only have to run one cron job instead of two???

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the backup (#1) script call the upload (#2) script via a URL when it is finished.

```
# Script Number 1 - Backup
/* After all the content */
@file_get_contents( 'http://www.yourserver.com/uploadToS3.php?protector=somethingSecret' );

# Script Number 2 - Uploader (available at the URL above)
/* Before all the content */
if( $_GET['protector']!='somethingSecret' ){
  die( 'Access Blocked' );
}
```

This means that, when the Backup Script finished, it triggers the Upload Script. The `protector=somethingSecret` is just there to prevent it from being accidentally triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the cron job to run the second script after the first script. As in the command field of the cronjob would look something like this:

```
php -f firstscript.php ; php -f secondscript.php
```

I use this method on many of my cronjobs.